# Was not expected at this line "%isBackup%"=="y"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know this question has been asked a few times on SO, but for whatever reason, those answers did not solve my issues. The offending code is below. I am running it from a .bat file.

```
@echo off

goto :getSystemID

:getSystemID
set /p systemId="Please input the System ID - Example 'DD012345-xxxx' : " %=%

:getLocation
set /p isBackup="Is This a Backup Location? Backup Locations use 169.254.xxx.x (Y/N) : " %=%

if [/i] "%isBackup%"=="y" 
(
    set primaryIP = 169.254.xxx.x
    goto :end
)

:end
echo %isBackup%
```

Reguarless if I run it directly from the .bat or the if statement itself into the command line, I receive the same error:

```
"%isBackup%"=="y" was unexpected at this time.
```

What I've tried:

```
Removed: ""
Removed: [/i]
Changed: [/i] to [/I]
Removed variables: "y"=="y"
```

I'm very new to .bat files, any help is greatly appreciated.

### Update with Solution

```
 @echo off
    goto :getSystemID
    :getSystemID
    set /p systemId="Please input the System ID - Example 'DD012345-xxxx' : " %=%
    :getLocation
    set /p isBackup="Is This a Backup Location? Backup Locations use 169.254.xxx.x (Y/N) : " %=%
    if /i "%isBackup%"=="y" (
        set primaryIP = 169.254.130.1
        goto :end
    )
    :end
    echo  %isBackup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the bracket around `/i`

The syntax is `if /i operand1 operator operand2 somethingtodo`

the `[`..`]` shown in the documentation indicates that the `/i` and `not` are optional.

Currently, batch is interpreting `[/i]` as operand1 and `"%isBackup%"` as operator. It objects to the operator used.

If parentheses are used around the `if` 'target' then the <kbd>(</kbd> must be on the same line as the `if`

Similarly, the sequence <kbd>)</kbd> ELSE <kbd>(</kbd> (if used) must be on the same physical line, as must DO <kbd>(</kbd> in a `FOR` statement.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple! Removed the [] as mentioned and moved the ( to the same line as the if.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to move your `(` to be on the same line as the `if` statement. For example:

```
if "%isBackup%"=="y" (
    set primaryIP = 169.254.xxx.x
    goto :end
)
```

instead of:

```
if "%isBackup%"=="y" 
(
    set primaryIP = 169.254.xxx.x
    goto :end
)
```

Therefore the general format for `if-else` is:

```
if [condition] (
    REM actions to be taken if the condition is true...
) else (
    REM actions to be taken if the condition is false...
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tested with the ( on the same line, but still the same error. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Yea tried that, no luck. I also tried a single line for the if statement. if "%isBackup%"=="y" (set primaryIP = 169.254.xxx.x)

Comment: Don't have enough rep on this SO to upvote your answer, but your answer was very helpful!